# Pyinstaller and pygubu's calendar frame cause a problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pygubu

I made a pygubu python application, and decided I wanted to freeze it, after troubleshooting some simple problems, I ran into something I couldn't fix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 138, in <module>
  File "pygubu\__init__.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "main.py", line 38, in _create_ui
  File "pygubu\builder\__init__.py", line 166, in get_object
  File "pygubu\builder\__init__.py", line 215, in _realize
  File "pygubu\builder\__init__.py", line 215, in _realize
  File "pygubu\builder\__init__.py", line 225, in _realize
Exception: Class "pygubu.builder.widgets.calendarframe" not mapped
[13108] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I even imported a bunch of pyugubu modules to try to fix this, and it still didn't work:

```py
from pygubu import builder
from pygubu.builder import ttkstdwidgets
from pygubu.builder import widgets
from pygubu.widgets import calendarframe
from pygubu import widgets
```

This probably doesn't matter, but I froze it with auto-py-to-exe. I've tried making it a console application, folder application, and both at the same time, but it still didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `from pygubu.widgets.calendarframe import CalendarFrame`  stay on beginning of *pygubu/builder/widgets/calendarframe.py*  source and target not be same. Just use *Tkinter*  in your code (is very simple), understanding a module makes it easier to write a module. the bottom answer is not valid. Best Regards, have nice day.

Comment: @dsgdfg Pygubu makes it much easier and faster to create graphical interfaces for python, I was looking for a way to use one of the widgets it provided, not someone to tell me to go write my own tkinter code. matle's answer works flawlessly. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right (for starters), but if you don't know the element properties, typing correlation and condition functions will really challenge you. If you are really writing an app with Tkinter, it will definitely not use StringVar, IntVar and many definitions and will switch much faster.

Comment: I have made applications with Tkinter, I just prefer the ease of use pygubu provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Create test-project

Create **test.py** (adapted from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pygubu/)) (i included all the dependencies you mentioned and listed their attributes and methods to make sure the module is included):

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu
from pygubu import builder
from pygubu.builder import ttkstdwidgets
from pygubu.builder import widgets
from pygubu.widgets import calendarframe
from pygubu import widgets

class HelloWorldApp:
    
    def __init__(self):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('test.ui')

        #3: Create the mainwindow
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainwindow')
        
    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # just some calls to make sure the imports are loaded
    print(dir(pygubu))
    print(dir(builder))
    print(dir(ttkstdwidgets))
    print(dir(widgets))
    print(dir(calendarframe))
    print(dir(widgets))
    
    app = HelloWorldApp()
    app.run()
```

Create **test.ui**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<interface>
  <object class="tk.Toplevel" id="mainwindow">
    <property name="height">200</property>
    <property name="resizable">both</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Hello World App</property>
    <property name="width">200</property>
    <child>
      <object class="ttk.Frame" id="mainframe">
        <property name="height">200</property>
        <property name="padding">20</property>
        <property name="width">200</property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">0</property>
          <property name="propagate">True</property>
          <property name="row">0</property>
          <property name="sticky">nsew</property>
          <rows>
            <row id="0">
              <property name="weight">1</property>
            </row>
          </rows>
          <columns>
            <column id="0">
              <property name="weight">1</property>
            </column>
          </columns>
        </layout>
        <child>
          <object class="ttk.Label" id="label1">
            <property name="anchor">center</property>
            <property name="font">Helvetica 26</property>
            <property name="foreground">#0000b8</property>
            <property name="text" translatable="yes">Hello World !</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="propagate">True</property>
              <property name="row">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

#### 2. Install pyinstaller and pygubu

```
pip install pyinstaller pygubu
```

#### 3. Copy pygubu module to local project

1. Navigate to site-packages folder of current interpreter (execute in shell:
   `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[-1])"`, navigate to returned path)
2. Copy entire `pygubu` folder to location with `test.py` script

One-liner from within the folder containing `test.py`:

```
python -c "import shutil, site, os; shutil.copytree(site.getsitepackages()[-1]+os.sep+'pygubu', os.getcwd()+os.sep+'pygubu')"
```

#### 4. Run pyinstaller, test package

The following statement adds the `.ui` file as well as the entire pygubu package directly. Afterwards, run the `test.exe` from within the `dist/test` folder.

```
pyinstaller --clean --add-data=test.ui;. --add-data pygubu;pygubu test.py
```

---

I tried running pyinstaller with `--onefile` which did not work, `--hidden-import`, `--collect-data`, `--collect-submodules` and `--collect-all` also failed. This is quite an ugly solution, however.

---

### Edit

After discovering what an awesome module auto-py-to-exe is (thank you for mentioning it), i discovered that you can use `--collect-all` in combination with `--onefile` without the need of copying the `pygubu` library by hand. However, i could not manage to include the .ui file, so that i had to copy manually:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --collect-all "pygubu"  "test.py" && python -c "import shutil, os; shutil.copyfile('test.ui', 'dist'+os.sep+'test.ui')"
```

Comment: There's a section about `Additional Files` in auto-py-to-exe if you scroll down just a bit, it lets you include files. Your solution worked, thank you so much.

Comment: @ParasolKirby Glad it worked out :)